# How to hold the values of the JSF 1.2 listbox after validation fails

Tags: javascript, jsf, listbox

i am using JSf 1.2 and i am currently showing a list in that listbox.Now my problem is  that i am selecting the values from that listbox and the form is submitted.So when returning to the page the selected value is missing.How i will hold the value in my code?i am posting the code

```
 <h:panelGroup styleClass="panelGroup" id="grpMemDep"> 
                                            <h:selectOneMenu id="memDepCode" styleClass="inputfont" onchange="getMemberDepInfo();">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="----SELECT----" itemValue="0"/>
                                                    <f:selectItems id="selectItems32"
                                                        value="#{searchUserProfileBean.memberDependentList}" />
                                                </h:selectOneMenu>

                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                      <hx:commandExButton type="submit" value="submit"
                                                styleClass="commandExButton"
                                                id="getAllMemberDepInformation" action="#{pc_userManagementProfile.doGetAllMemDepInfoAction}" style="display:none">

                                            </hx:commandExButton>   




   function getMemberDepInfo(){


document.getElementById('vwmyUserProfile:myUserProfileForm:getAllMemberDepInformation').click();
}
```

and in the service i am using this java code to get the listbox values

```
 List<DependentDTO> dependentList = new MemberProxy()
            .getDependentListFormMember( loggedInUser
                    .getUserAccessList().get(0).getClientCode(),
                    loggedInUser
                    .getUserAccessList().get(0).getCertificateNumber());
            List<SelectItem> selList=new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

            for(DependentDTO depDTO:dependentList){

                SelectItem sel = new SelectItem();
                sel.setLabel(depDTO.getNameFirst());
                sel.setValue(depDTO.getCertNumber()+"#"+depDTO.getClientCode()+"#"+depDTO.getDependentCode());
                selList.add(sel);   
            }
             mem = new MemberProxy().getMemberDetails(loggedInUser
                        .getUserAccessList().get(0).getClientCode(), loggedInUser
                        .getUserAccessList().get(0).getCertificateNumber());

             SelectItem sel = new SelectItem();
             sel.setLabel(mem.getNameFirst());
             sel.setValue(mem.getCertNumber().toString().trim()+"#"+mem.getClientCode().toString().trim());
             selList.add(sel);

            memberDependent.setMemberDependentList(selList);
```

I am using a hidden button to submit.Please show me how i will hold the values

Comment: Please [format properly](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

In the searchUserProfileBean you can add a private property, with the getter and setter

```
private DependentDTO listboxValue;
```

In your page

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="memDepCode" styleClass="inputfont" value="#{searchUserProfileBean.listboxValue}" onchange="getMemberDepInfo();">
```

Now you have binding of the selected value.